# When I slow down at an intersection or lights, my engine light comes in

Tags: engine, exhaust, lights, smoke

I have a 2005 PT Cruiser Turbo and with in the last week, when I slow down, and come to a stop, my engine light comes on.
Also, when I start my car in the morning, there is a cloud of white exhaust smoke. Any ideas for me?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was thinking that the white smoke may be coolant or something. It only last for a moment, and then it was gone. I will be going to the mechanic on Saturday with this new knowledge. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Some cars use the "check engine" light for the oil pressure. That would explain it; at low engine RPM the oil pressure drops enough to turn on the light. It could result from oil viscosity too low or , more likely , the bearings are getting "tired", clearance is too great. Try higher oil viscosity ; use 30 W instead of 10W , etc.

Answer (score 0):

We need some clarification...is it the engine light or the oil pressure light.

If idle causes the oil pressure light to come on, you may have a bad sensor or your may have insufficient oil pressure at idle.  The best approach is to measure the pressure with a gauge.  Then depending upon what you find, you might replace the sensor.

If it is the "check" engine light, that normally indicates that the ECU has provided a code, and that can be read with an ODB-II reader.  You can usually borrow a reader at a parts store to read the codes there.  Let us know what you find.

In the morning, the start could be: coolant, some incomplete burnt products from bad timing, incomplete injection or other causes.  Does it go away after 5 minutes?

Ideas?  Yes, check your oil pressure.  Are you loosing any coolant; check that.  Are you loosing any oil--what is your consumption over mileage?

More data is needed to help you solve this, so report back...

Answer (score 0):

White smoke is usually water, i.e. coolant; blue smoke is oil.  So your white smoke could well be coolant that leaks in the cool(ing) engine.  This may –or not- be involved with the code that you’re checking.